# Can't resolve component inside component library when using NPM link

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a react application initialised with CRA, as well as a stand alone component library.
I'm trying to use `npm link` so that I can test my changes in the component library locally.

To do this I am running
`npm link` in the component library, then
`npm link @my-react\component-library` in my create react app.

This all seems to work successfully, however when I try to start my application, none of the components within my component library can be resolved.

The following error is returned

`Can't resolve '@my-react/component-library/tooltip' in 'C:\react-app\src\components\page'`

followed by

`Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'`

`Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'`

I've googled and tried to set `symLinks` to `false`, which didnt work.
Also of note, my component library doesn't have an index.js file as its just a bunch of components that are imported when needed.

If an index.js file is required, what should it contain?
If not, what else could cause this problem?

Page component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tooltip } from '@my-react/component-library/tooltip' 

export const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is my page</h1>
      <Tooltip />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your PAGE component ?

Comment: There is not much in the Page component as im still developing, just a reference to the Tooltip in the component library

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have auto imported something in your page component. Check if there is any unused import. Delete that and it should work fine.

Comment: It seems to fail as soon as it tries to import my Tooltip component from the component library